# Should I buy Dummit and Foote as a secondary textbook for my algebra courses?

Tags: abstract-algebra

I have taken a course in abstract algebra, which used Fraleigh's book. This semester I'm taking a course called Rings and Modules, which uses Bhattacharya's book, which is fine for the most part, but sometimes I can't understand the material. Today after the lecture I spoke to my professor, and he told me he thought some explanations and constructions in the book aren't very good.

So I have Fraleigh, which is insufficient for the material I'm studying now, and I have Bhattacharya which sometimes confuses me. I've heard so much about Dummit and Foote, so I'm wondering if it's worth the cost of buying it now only to improve my understanding of certain topics? I'm also planning on taking Galois theory next semester, and if Dummit and Foote covers that as well, I suppose that's another reason to buy it because the Galois course at my university also uses Bhattacharya.

Comment: I have Dummit and Foote as well as Fraleigh and they're ok but my all time favorite by a long shot is Hungerford.  I can't say enough good things about it.

Comment: @GregoryGrant, which one in particular would that be? I found a lot of books by Hungerford on amazon

Comment: @Auclair This one: http://smile.amazon.com/Algebra-Graduate-Texts-Mathematics-v/dp/0387905189/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1446835475&sr=1-1&keywords=hungerford

Comment: @Auclair: If you want to work in Algebra or Algebraic Geometry, you should start looking at Serge Lang's Algebra also.

Comment: @Babai cool, thanks for the tips. I am interested in Algebra, and my bachelor thesis is sort of related to Algebraich Geometry

Comment: Couldn't you just consult a copy in your university's library instead of buying it? During my years as a student I bought very few books, relying heavily on my university's library...

Answer (score 4):

I cannot recommend Dummit and Foote highly enough.  I first bought this book about 6 years ago as my second algebra book.  It has been the text for 3 of the algebra courses I have taken, and I still use it regularly today.

D&F is an excellent reference on a wide variety of topics in algebra.  Foote is a group theorist by trade (his advisor was Thompson of the [classification of finite simple groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classification_of_finite_simple_groups)), so the first six chapters on group theory provide a lucid exposition of the subject from a true expert.  The chapters on rings, modules, fields, and Galois theory are similarly well-written, with many useful examples from number theory.

The later chapters are fantastic as well, and provide solid foundations to pursue deeper study in algebraic geometry, algebraic number theory, and representation theory.

Dummit and Foote is not as encyclopedic as some textbooks, notably Lang's, but is **much** friendlier to read.  Many times, after struggling to understand the proof of a commutative algebra result in Lang or Zariski-Samuel or Atiyah-MacDonald, I turned to D&F and found a clean, approachable explanation in  that I should have started with in the first place.  Just yesterday I was looking fruitlessly for a proof of the classification of finitely generated modules over a Dedekind domain, when I found that it was sitting right under my nose in Chapter 16 of D&F.

Anyway, I think I've sung this book's praises enough, so I'll just re-emphasize that I found this book immensely useful when I first got it, and continue to find it useful today, years later.

Answer (score 0):

Dummit and Foote is a very good supplement as well as Maclane and Birkhoff's "Algebra 3rd ed."

Answer (score 0):

Yes definitely you can go for Dummit and Foote. It is an excellent book and covers wide variety of topics with clear explanations and very good exercises. I, myself is currently reading the book and I find it quite useful then Gallian. While Gallian is good for the first course in algebra but Dummit will give you a better understanding of the topics. Yes it also covers Galois theory as well. You can also check out Herstein's book, it is a classic. Also you can read Serg Lang's Algebra , which is another good book in algebra.